# Magento admin separate  ajax product Grid load

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

I have to load separate product Grid to select needed product items and store it under my another custom module's model in magento admin side.

So i have a custom module created by using Module creator and added another tab which i wish to show all the products as a list or grid to select(Exactly i want it like in new order page under admin side) and store.

Do you anybody know how to load product grid or list under custom module area.

I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Hi Ela, Have u ever got the chance to finish your module. If so, could you please share your codes
Thanks 
- Ponnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ela,

I won't walk through all the steps to do this here, but I'll tell you how I did this.  Basically if you look at the Google Base folder under app/core you'll find some really good hint on how to add a product grid to your module.

Basically whee you're going to be doing is defining a block that overrides Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.  From there you override a few basic functions such as __construct(), _prepareCollection() and _prepareColumns() (there may be a few others) and then magic-ento does most of the hard work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris. I have got loaded the grid but facing problem with the grid reloding options. Once i done i will post answer here

Comment: If you're having problems with the grid reloading then check your getGridUrl() function.  I was just messing with a grid the other day and that was a problem that I ran into.